# Taylor Series - Write $1 + 2x -x^2 + 5x^3 - x^4$ at powers of $(x-1) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Exercise: Write the polynomial $1 + 2x -x^2 + 5x^3 - x^4$ at powers of $(x-1)$.

I presume this exercise is solved using Taylor Series, since it belongs to that chapter, but have no idea how to solve it. Otherwise, it's very straightforward.

Note: The above exercise is **not** homework.

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of a Taylor series around $x=1$?

Comment: To answer, that would be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} f^{\(k)} (x-1)^{k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do that is to do just what you would do with any other function:

Calculate $$p(1), p'(1), p''(1)...$$ (strait-forward since $p$ is a polynomial)

and use the derivatives to build the appropriate taylor series around $x_0 = 1$

Indeed, it is considerably faster (in this case) than the method proposed by Mark Bennet

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method. Let $t=x-1$ so that $x=t+1$.

$$p(t)=1+2(t+1)-(t+1)^2+5(t+1)^3-(t+1)^4$$

Then it is just arithmetic to get the answer.

You can also use Taylor Series - sometimes these problems are set to solve by Taylor Series to show the method works.